# Fall down elements in 2d array

Tags: c#

Hello looking for simple loop where numbers will fall down in 2d array for example

```
0 0 0 3 3
2 1 3 1 1
1 1 5 1 1
1 2 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 2
```

expected:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 3
2 1 0 3 1
1 1 3 1 1
1 2 5 1 2
```

Do you have suggestions? Thank you.

Hint: Fall down means non-zero items must go down in each column!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code, please. Do you want a single step in "falling down" or immediately the shown result?

Comment: I want just immediately the shown result.

Comment: You should edit the question to include you code instead of putting it into a comment.

Comment: How did you declare your "2D" array?  There are different interpretations of what that means, and the approach required for each would be just as different!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
void FallDown(ref int[,] numbers)
{
    var rowCount = numbers.GetLength(0);
    for (var c = 0; c < numbers.GetLength(1); c++)
    {
        var colValues = new List<int>();
        for (var r = 0; r < rowCount; r++)
        {
            var colValue = numbers[r, c];
            if (colValue > 0)
            {
                colValues.Add(colValue); // collect only non-zero values
            }
        }
        if (colValues.Count < rowCount) // there were zeroes ...
        {
            do
            {
                colValues.Insert(0, 0); // fill it up with leading zeroes.
            } while (colValues.Count < rowCount);
            for (var r = 0; r < rowCount; r++) {
                numbers[r, c] = colValues[r]; // put numbers back into original array
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result will be replaced in the original array, which is why it is passed in by `ref`.

Answer (score 0):

Found this.

```
  public void FallDown()
   {

        for (var row = 0; row < RowCount - 1; row++)
        {

            for (var column = 0; column < ColumnCount; column++)
            {
                if (tiles[row + 1, column] == 0 && tiles[row, column] != 0)
                {
                    tiles[row + 1, column] = tiles[row, column];
                    tiles[row, column] = 0;
                    row = 0;
                    column = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```